# build a custom image compatible with python azure function using red hat as a base image

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I had  a use case where the azure functions had to be deployed as docker container in function app . but can not use the Microsoft base image for python azure function(docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.9).
had to use the own golden image (Red Hat 8) which is had python 3.8 installed on it. how to use this base image to build a another custom image to make it compatible with azure functions.
does installing the 1) azure core functions tools and
2) azure cli
is enough to make it compatible with azure functions. tried to find the document for this use case but no document is available on this.

any guidance is helpful

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the `func` CLI, it would be better just getting the actual host like the production images, since the CLI is more designed for local development.

You can take the [dockerfile for the production image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/dev/host/4/bullseye/amd64/python/python38/python38.Dockerfile) and swap out [this line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/dev/host/4/bullseye/amd64/python/python38/python38.Dockerfile#L43) with your golden image. The following lines will also have to be changed as required by your image (like use yum instead of apt-get, for example).

The first half of the dockerfile is just building the functions runtime in the dotnet container and fetching the extension bundle which can still be the same.